# How to completely disable syntax higlighting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I'm unable to completely disable syntax highlighting for Java source code files in Notepad++.

I've commented out the Java sections in **langs.model.xml** and **stylers.model.xml** (even tried deleting those files to no avail) but if I create a new file and then save a file with .java extension then, bang! syntax colouring kicks in. Grrrrr. any way to do this?

You might think it's an absurd requirement but I'm preparing a Java certification and it's better to practise programming with no syntax help at all but I still like to use Notepad++ because I'm used to it and for its other features (multi-tabbed interface, reopen last used files... etc) instead of crappy plain old win notepad.

Thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why commenting out the relevant sections did not work - was Notepad++ closed when you did that?

An alternative method is to disable the language from within Notepad++ and then add a user defined language assigned to the `java` extension.

1. Go to `Settings` > `Preferences` > `Language Menu/Tab Settings`.
2. Select `Java` on the `Available items` list.
3. Click the arrow to add it to the `Disabled items` list.

   [[image: Screenshot of settings]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdL0c.png)
4. Go to `View` > `User-Defined Dialogue...`.
5. `Create New...`, name it whatever you like. I named it `Java_normal`.
6. Add `java` to the `Ext.` textbox.

   [[image: Screenshot of dialogue]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLox8.png)
7. Close the `User Defined Language` window.
8. Restarting Notepad++ may be necessary.

Comment: Already done that, it doesn't help. As I understand it this preference modification just removes it from the interface, that is, Java disappears from the "Language" menu which lists available languages but not from the program "internals". If you create a new file and save it with .java ext it will still colourize it.

Comment: @b4nd0ler0 Updated, this one should work. The user defined language with no highlighting should override the built in one - and I've actually tested making a new/saving/opening a `.java` file. There's more details at the official wiki, [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages#Overriding_a_built-in_language).

Comment: That definitively works. Thank you so much, you're a star. For the record I have also disabled the built-in brace matching in Prefs.>Misc.>Highlight matching tags

Comment: What about just setting the current document to normal text mode?

Comment: @Royi The question asked about Java source in general, so having to change the language every time you open a file is probably not great.

Comment: I meant I have regular text in Notepad++. By mistake I set the language to, let say `C`. I now want to go back to text only mode (Not Syntax Highlighting), How can I do that?

Comment: @Royi Could you not just reopen the file? Anyway, you're probably better off asking a new question - I've not used Notepad++ in years.

Comment: What if it is not a saved file (Just started writing)?